# UIButtons from different views add images to same view?

Tags: iphone

So, I am building an application with different views. Each of them has a number of buttons. When pressing a button in a view, it should add an image to a addedImages view (the main one).
How do I make a loop that will add the images dynamically according to the position of previously added images?
Im quite new in this, so now I have only one button adding an image like this:

```
- (IBAction)addItemToShoppingList
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 100, 80, 80);
    [shoppingList.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

}
```

So I wanna make a function addItemToShoppingList that will be associated to all buttons in different views but to put different images dynamically to the same one?

Answer (score 0):

```
int shoppingListX; 

- (IBAction)addItemToShoppingList
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.jpg"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(shoppingListX, 100, 80, 80);
    shoppingListX += 80;

    [shoppingList.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

}
```

Comment: Thanx but thats not completely what I need.

So, I need a variable that will be keeping track of the location of the last pressed button (added image) so it can add them in a line to a shoppingList.

Different views represent different categories (vegetables, Fruits etc.), when you enter a Fruit view you choose a button Apple and by pressing it you add an apple image to your shopping list (another view).

So I need an advice how to solve positioning images on the shopping list itself since all view are represented by different classes. Something like a global variable?

Thanks for your help!